# Very long delay loading tiles on panning, but they load immediately when zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a strange problem with Google maps and it is happening with all the 3.X versions I tried. When I am panning the map the new tiles do not load, when I zoom (in/out - does not matter) - they load as expected. If I leave the page alone the missing tiles start loading after a very long delay - over a minute. I used Fiddler to check if there are any hanging requests - I found none - when sent they return quickly, so there is no networking problem involved. I noticed also that the standard controls (the zoom control) load with the same delay as well. This is happening in both IE and Chrome, I decided there is no point in trying it in other browsers - it is obviously something common.

Everything else works - I am showing lines and polygons, even editing them and reading back the edited vertices, however this affects also things like markers and I am receiving a DOM exception for them (with the same long delay).

Unfortunately it will be very difficult to pass any source code along. I am using the maps in a very complex windowing plus data binding javascript environment and I blame it for the issue, but all the diagnostics I have made show no problem anywhere. I debugged the application and there is not even a trace of a problem, delays cannot be caused by the environment (It is my work, so I know it from top to bottom) and the only possibility for a mix up I can imagine lies in some methods I am attaching to the Function object - otherwise there is no spot where the both can possibly collide. The strangest thing is the delay - if it broke I'd probably have already found it.

Any similar problems, anyone? Even a description of the problem under different circumstances may prove helpful I suppose. I searched for any similar issues, but found nothing of the sort.